# Using unmanaged dll with c#

Tags: c#, c++

I've been trying to create a c# wrapper for a c++ class I have created. I've looked around on how to do this but none of the examples seem to use classes and objects. I have the following code in c++:

```
#ifndef PORTAUDIOMANAGER_H
#define PORTAUDIOMANAGER_H

#include "portaudio.h"
#include "pa_asio.h"

class PortAudioManager
{
public:
    PortAudioManager();
    virtual ~PortAudioManager();

    static PortAudioManager* createObject();
    void openStream();

    void dispose(PortAudioManager* obj);

    void stopStream();

    typedef struct
    {
        float left_phase;
        float right_phase;
    }
    paTestData;

private:
    void* stream;

    paTestData data;
    static PortAudioManager* audioManager;
};

#endif
```

The `createObject` method creates a new object of PortAudioManager and registers it to the audioManager pointer. The `dispose` method acts as the destructor (since I thought you can't use the constructor and destructor in C#).

So how it should be used is simply like this:

```
PortAudioManager manager = PortAudioManager.createObject();
manager.openStream();
```

How would I go about creating a system that this can be used in c#?
If you need more information, let me know.

Comment: I suggest you wrap your native C++ class within a C++/CLI class. C++/CLI is an extension that allows C++ code to expose and consume CLI (.NET) code.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-minutes

Would this information suffice? It has a part "Wrapping Around a Native C++ Class"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new class library project and compile with the /clr flag. Given the native C++ class presented above, add the following C++/CLI class to wrap your native class:

```
public ref class PortAudioManagerManaged
{
private:
    PortAudioManagerManaged(PortAudioManager* native)
        : m_native(native) { }

public:
    PortAudioManagerManaged()
        : m_native(new PortAudioManager) { }

    // = IDisposable.Dispose
    virtual ~PortAudioManagerManaged() {
        this->!PortAudioManagerManaged();
    }

    // = Object.Finalize
    !PortAudioManagerManaged() {
        delete m_native;
        m_native = nullptr;
    }

    static PortAudioManagerManaged^ CreateObject()
    {
        return gcnew PortAudioManagerManaged(PortAudioManager::createObject());
    }

    void OpenStream()
    {
        if (!m_native)
            throw gcnew System::ObjectDisposedException(GetType()->FullName);
        m_native->openStream(); 
    }

    void StopStream()
    {
        if (!m_native)
            throw gcnew System::ObjectDisposedException(GetType()->FullName);
        m_native->stopStream(); 
    }

private:
    PortAudioManager* m_native;
};
```

In your C# project, add a reference to your C++/CLI class library.

```
using (PortAudioManagerManaged manager = PortAudioManagerManaged.CreateObject())
{
    manager.OpenStream();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I got that far already. Now, when I try to use the dll in Unity (which I might've needed to mention in the original question) I can add the dll as a reference and it works as it should (I can create an object and call its methods) but Unity can't seem to find the managed class. Any idea on that issue?

Comment: I never used Unity, sorry about that. You might want to post another question regarding interop between Unity and mixed-mode assemblies.

Comment: ok! I think I'll post that question on the Unity forums though. Thanks a lot for all the help!